# Register a DevArt LinqConnect model in a Blazor /.NET Core application

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, devart

I can find 1000's of example of how to register an EF model in a Blazor .NET Core application but almost nothing for any other provider.

I am using DevArt LinqConnect Model as my ORM but cannot find how to register it with the dependency injection container in my Blazor application.

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services. // what goes here?   
}
```

Any help?

UPDATE

I failed to mention that the underlying database is a SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You should create Devart EF Core Model *.efml (product [Entity Developer for Entity Framework](https://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/)) instead of Devart LinqConnect Model *.lqml (product [LinqConnect](https://www.devart.com/linqconnect/)) to follow the tutorials like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

Comment: But I am using (not by choice) LinqConnect. Devart EF Core Model isn't even an option.

Comment: .AddDbContextFactory() is EF Core-specific extension, there is no way to use it with LinqConnect model. But you can avoid context's registration in service, just create an instance of the context and construct your LINQ queries. For example: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/blazor/common/samples/3.x/BlazorSample_Server. Only one sample here is for EF Core. No service registration is done in other samples.

Comment: I am unable to locate the example. Could you tell which file(s) I should be looking at?

Comment: For example, /BlazorSample_Server/Data/WeatherForecast.cs generates some data, but you can create your context and construct LINQ query there.